# Android: build.gradle: Failed to resolve: com.github.Yalantis:Context-Menu.Android:1.1.4

Tags: android

I'm trying use a beautiful menu using the implementation in the build.gradle
    `implementation 'com.github.Yalantis:Context-Menu.Android:1.1.4'
and in the build.gradle, I'm using

```
maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
```

and  `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'`
but I receive this error
build.gradle: Failed to resolve: com.github.Yalantis:Context-Menu.Android:1.1.4
someone has had this error? thanks

Answer (score 0):

> add in project build.gradle

```
buildscript {
       dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3
                    }
           }

        allprojects {
            repositories {
                google()
                jcenter()
                maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
            }
        }
```

> add in app build.gradle

```
dependencies {

    implementation 'com.github.Yalantis:Context-Menu.Android:1.1.4'

}
```